# Code style per project in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I have to develop several Java projects with different code styles at the same time. How to configure in Intellij Idea code style per project?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html

Answer (score 19):

If you go to the Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style, there is a combo box at the top to choose to apply code style settings to the Project only, or at the global level.

[image]